# SYSTEM user in Task scheduler, Access denied to folder with Full control rights

Tags: file-permissions, windows-server-2008, windows-task-scheduler

I would like to execute exe file that will write some in some destination folder. I chose SYSTEM user as I don't want to take care about changing passwords or create user just for this task and I would like to execute task wether any user is logged on or not.
Destination folder has Full control rights for SYSTEM user but anyway returns message "Access denied".

Has anyone some suggestion on what rights should I use (except simple User rights, this works) to enable SYSTEM user to write in some destination folder?

Or should I use some other user for this kind of job and what rights should I use in that case?

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to help you if we can't see how you actually setup your task. A screenshot or two would work nice I think.

That said, On the general tab, make sure you check "Run with highest privileges"